# Searching database table through get method in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am new to django and having trouble to get result from my models database table through 'GET' method.

my **model** is:

```
class records(models.Model):
    sex = (('M', 'MALE'),('F', 'FEMALE'),)
    reg_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mic_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    dog_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dog_breed = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dog_Sex = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=sex)
    Breeder = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=264)
```

my **views** is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime
from .forms import RecordForm
from .models import records

# Create your views here.
def index (request):
    return render(request, "newyear/index.html")

def search (request):
    mic = request.GET['mic']
    r = records.objects.filter(mic_number__iexact = mic )
    return render(request,"newyear/search.html", {"records": r})
```

my **index** template is:

```
<form action="{% url 'search'%}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="GET">
    <ul><input type="text" name = "mic"></ul>
  <button type="submit" name= "search">search</button>
</form>
```

my **search** template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>THIS IS RESULT PAGE</h1>
  {% if records %}
  <table>
    {% for records in records %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{records.color}}</td>
      <td>{{records.dog_name}}</td>
      <td>{{records.mic_number}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
  {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

`search.html` only displays "THIS IS RESULT PAGE". what is wrong in above approach please help. I am struggling from 3 days on it.

Comment: Search.html only displays " THIS IS RESULT PAGE". what is wrong in above approach please help. I am struggling from 3 days on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The looping variable(`records`) is same as looped details(`records`).So please change `records` to `record` like this. And Change `GET` method to `POST`.

```
<h1>THIS IS RESULT PAGE</h1>
  {% if records %}
  <table>
    {% for record in records %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{record.color}}</td>
      <td>{{record.dog_name}}</td>
      <td>{{record.mic_number}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
  {% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
def search (request):
    mic = request.POST['mic']
    r = records.objects.filter(mic_number__iexact = mic )
    return render(request,"newyear/search.html", {"records": r})
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'search'%}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST">
    <ul><input type="text" name = "mic"></ul>
  <input type="submit" value="search" name= "search">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried it, but still it does not show any record. Page remains blank.

Comment: Check `records` this is empty ?? By add  `{{records}}` to template.

Comment: no, records is not empty, when i remove everything and send query records.objects.all() it shows all records also if i input mic_number manually and remove mic it shows result. Problem is it is not taking argument from form.

Comment: `mic_number` in database value must enter in manually (`index` url ) then display detail. I think this error is your mistake. I run it in my local with correct answer.

Comment: yes it worked, thanks a lot buddy. I am so sooo relieved.